# Can't connect to (or even find) Canon LBP 3500 printer on my network

Tags: networking, printing

There's a Canon LBP 3500 printer on my office network.
I don't know its IP.
It doesn't show up when I scan the local subnet with nmap.
I cannot find the manual (hardcopy or online).
It is plugged into the network.
It is turned on.
I have turned it off and on again.
I have tried plugging it into other ports on our switch.

Any recommended further steps to take?

Comment: Have you installed the appropriate drivers?

Comment: [Drivers located and installed](http://support-au.canon.com.au/contents/AU/EN/0900788602.html)
||  
[Manual located](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300003039/01/LBP3500_UsersGuide_en-uv_1.pdf)
||  
Still no success.

Comment: Additional info: on the network board, LNK and 100 are both lit up green. ERR is not lit up.

Comment: Additional info: the printer seems to be functioning as expected via a USB connection.  The problem is with recognizing the printer over the network.

Comment: Solution: turned out to be a faulty switch.

Answer (score 1):

Faulty switch -- not a printer problem.